# What's happening with my chilli leaves?

Tags: plant-health, leaves, chili

My chili plant was fine a couple days ago, we had a week of unexpected hot weather (30 celcius) which has now cooled back down to around 22, but I've noticed all the leaves on my plant suddenly look like this.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Is there any chance that the plant dried out at some point, particularly during the heat wave?

Comment: Too hot for a Mexican plant? No.

Comment: @YosefBaskin  I don't think Stephie was talking about to much heat as much as the heat causing the soil to dry out and the plant to suffer from being unable to take up water.   I am no expert but to me this does look like lack of water.